# How to remove empty values in a DataTable rows and merge

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to figure out a good way to remove empty values from rows and merge `row2` to `row1`, `row4` to `row2`  in a datatable.

DataTable with Empty rows to merge

```
      ---------------------
      | Column1 | Column2 | 
      ----------------------
ROW1  | XYZ     |          |       
ROW2  |         | ABC      | 
ROW3  | MNQ     |          |
ROW4  |         | PQR      |
```

Final datatable with merged rows

```
      _____________________
      | Column1 | Column2 | 
      ----------------------
ROW1  | XYZ    |  ABC     |       
ROW2  | MNQ    |   PQR    |
```

Can somebody help me accomplish this in  C#?

Comment: Will the it be alternatively empty  always ? What if Row 5 and 6 has Column1 but no column 2 ?

Comment: yes.it is alternatively empty always

Answer (score 0):

Try to create two array that will store a column1 value and column2 value.
In loop go through all datatable rows and insert all not empty rows from column1 to array1 and rows from column2  to array2. Then on the end create new datatable that will have rows taked from array1 and array2. 
For example in pseudocode.

```
    var array1;
    var array2;
    for(var row in datatable)
    {
      if(row[column1] != null or empty)array1.push(row[column1].value);
      if(row[column2] != null or empty)array2.push(row[column2].value);
}
```

and in the end (first check what array is biger).For example i assuming that array1 is bigger;

```
var newDatatable;

for(int i=0; i<array1.count; i++)
{
var row = new row;
newDatatable.row[column1].addRowValue(array1[i])
if(array2.count < i){
newDatatable.row[column2].addRowValue(array2[i])
}

}
```